Android browser with extensions able to open local HTML files
I am looking for an Android browser which supports extensions and which is able to open and display an HTML file with JS/CSS included dependencies located on the local filesystem.
I have tried many broswers :

Opera, can open local files in /storage/xxx/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/, but no extensions
Chrome, cannot open local HTML, but no extensions
Kiwi, cannot open local HTML, but support extensions (and dev tools!)
Firefox, cannot open local HTML, and support extension
Firefox for Developers, same as above with a different theme (what a joke...)
Samsung default browser, like Chrome.

Note that most of these browsers can open a downloaded file, but not dependencies in an HTML file.
Also, I am not looking for a local HTTP server workaround.
